# Printing out a table horizontal instead of vertical using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

**Problem:**

I have a table that prints out vertical but I would like it to print horizontal instead. Anyone who can give guidance on how this can be achieved?

**PHP code:**

```
echo '
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered neutralize">     
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Kriterium</td>
                <td><b>Betyg</td>
            </tr>
';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$i.'</td>
            <td>'.$row['RID'].'</td>
        </tr>
    ';

    $i++;
}

echo '
        </tbody>
    </table>
';
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: You're mixing up the td and the tr tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Loop through your query results first building up the two rows that you want and then add them into your table afterwards:

```
$kriterium = '';
$betyg = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $kriterium .= '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
    $betyg .= '<td>'.$row['RID'].'</td>';
    $i++;
}

echo '
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered neutralize">     
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Kriterium</td>'.$kriterium .'
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Betyg</td>'.$betyg .'
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
';
```

Comment: is `.=` and `+=` the same thing in PHP

Comment: No, `.=` is the concatenating assignment operator whereas `+=` is the addition assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect data in two dimensional array and later reuse this array to build output in different formats:

```
$rows  = array();
$index = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $rows[0][] = ++$index;
    $rows[1][] = $row['RID'];
}

$table = '<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered neutralize">     
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><b>Kriterium</b></td><td>%s</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Betyg</b></td><td>%s</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>';

printf(
  $table, 
  implode('</td><td>', $rows[0]),
  implode('</td><td>', $rows[1])
);
```