# Fixed column width with changing no. of columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, width

I have a horizontal table that have a changing number of columns. 
How do I set a fixed column width? I have tried to set width in the main table setup and in the tr and td tags. No luck so far.
Any suggestions?

Here is my code

...mysql query

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $file_no .= '<td>'.$row['File_no'].'</td>';
    $user .= '<td>'.$row['User'].'</td>';
    $movement .='<td>'.$row['Downloaded']. " &nbsp " .$row['Uploaded'].'</td>';

    $i++;
}


echo '
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr align="center"> 
            <td align="left"><b>File no.</b></td>'.$file_no .'
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td align="left"><b>User</b></td>'.$user .'
        </tr>
         <tr align="center">
            <td align="left"><b>Movement</b></td>'.$movement .'
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928849/setting-table-column-width  should be helpful

Comment: I have set the tr td tags to different values, f. ex. <td/tr width="100"> and the main table setup like <table width="auto" border="1">

Comment: You forgot to close your `<b>` tags...

Comment: Well, I was looking for a horizontal table setup and found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001426/printing-out-a-table-horizontal-instead-of-vertical-using-php

Comment: There is no reason why your width isn't working except the table is to wide and the columns results in smaller width because of that. Here is a test: http://codepad.org/ys8q8PLi

Comment: My table width is dynamic because of the changing no. of columns. That is also why I can't set the total table width.