# Treat data from mysql for html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to treat data from mysql for display in HTML, using PHP.
I have three database tables: student, course, student_x_course

student:

```
| idStudent | firstname | surname |
-----------------------------------
| 1         | John      | Regular | 
| 2         | John      | Smith   | 
| 3         | Claire    | White   |
```

course:

```
| idCourse  | coursename |
--------------------------
| 1         | Art        | 
| 2         | Music      |
| 3         | Math       |
| 3         | Biology    |
```

student_x_course:

```
| idsc | idStudent | idCourse |
-------------------------------
| 1    | 1         | 1        |
| 2    | 1         | 2        |
| 3    | 1         | 3        |
| 4    | 2         | 1        |
| 5    | 2         | 2        |
| 6    | 2         | 4        |
| 7    | 3         | 1        |
| 8    | 3         | 2        |
| 9    | 3         | 3        |
| 10   | 3         | 4        |
```

And I want to create an html table which looks like this:

```
              | Art  | Music | Math  | Biology |
------------------------------------------------
John Regular  | x    | x     | x     | -       |
John Smith    | x    | x     | -     | x       |
Claire White  | x    | x     | x     | x       |
```

My sql query is:
SELECT s.firstname, s.surname, c.coursename FROM student AS s INNER JOIN student_x_course AS sxc ON (s.idStudent = sxc.idStudent) INNER JOIN course ON (c.idCourse = sxc.idCourse);

which gets me the following:

```
 | John   | Regular | Art     |
 | John   | Regular | Music   |
 | John   | Regular | Math    |
 | John   | Smith   | Art     |
 | John   | Regular | Music   |
 | John   | Smith   | Biology |
 | Claire | White   | Art     |
 | Claire | White   | Music   |
 | Claire | White   | Math    |
 | Claire | White   | Biology |
```

My question is: How can I get from many rows to lines?
Is there a better sql query or do I have to handle this in PHP Code?
Any suggestions?

Comment: This question might be useful in some way: [Printing out a table horizontal instead of vertical using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11001426/4577762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pivot your results.  In `mysql`, you can do this with `conditional aggregation`:

```
SELECT s.idStudent, s.firstname, s.surname, 
   max(case when c.coursename = 'Art' then 'x' end) Art,
   max(case when c.coursename = 'Music' then 'x' end) Music,
   max(case when c.coursename = 'Math' then 'x' end) Math,
   max(case when c.coursename = 'Biologoy' then 'x' end) Biologoy
FROM student AS s 
   INNER JOIN student_x_course AS sxc ON (s.idStudent = sxc.idStudent) 
   INNER JOIN course ON (c.idCourse = sxc.idCourse)
GROUP BY s.idStudent
```