# How to change table Rows and Column in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table:

```
<table>

    <tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>time1</td>      <td>time2</td>      <td>time3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-01-14</td>
      <td>yes</td>    <td>--</td>     <td>yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2017-01-17</td>
      <td>--</td>     <td>--</td>     <td>yes</td>
    </tr>   <tr>
      <td>2017-01-23</td>
      <td>--</td>     <td>yes</td>    <td>yes</td>
    </tr>   </table>
```

[image]

I want to change table, Rows and Column to:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>2017-01-14</td>
      <td>2017-01-17</td>
      <td>2017-01-23</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>time1</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>--</td>
      <td>--</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>time2</td>
      <td>--</td>
      <td>--</td>
      <td>yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>time3</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>yes</td>
      <td>yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to do all the changes at the same time?

Comment: Where is the PHP code that you have tried?  Also take a look at [Printing out a table horizontal instead of vertical using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001426/printing-out-a-table-horizontal-instead-of-vertical-using-php)