# Horizontal table instead of vertical with PHP

Tags: php

I created a horizontal html table with php using the suggested solution on this post: [Printing out a table horizontal instead of vertical using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001426/printing-out-a-table-horizontal-instead-of-vertical-using-php)

And my code is like this:

```
$sql="SELECT Pr1, Pr2, Pr3, Pr4 FROM Tbdata ORDER BY Date DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$Pr1 = '';
$Pr2 = '';
$Pr3 = '';
$Pr4 = '';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

    $Pr4 .= '<td>'.$row['Pr4'].'</td>';
    $Pr3 .= '<td>'.$row['Pr3'].'</td>';
    $Pr2 .= '<td>'.$row['Pr2'].'</td>';
    $Pr1 .= '<td>'.$row['Pr1'].'</td>';
}


echo '
    <table class="table">     
        <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td>'.$Pr4.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>'.$Pr3.'</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>'.$Pr2.'</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>'.$Pr1.'</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
'; 

?>
```

The code works fine. The only problem is that I extract data with Date DESC  in the query. For some reason, the data of **the most recent date** doesn't appear on the table.  What am I missing here? please Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample data for the `Tbdata` table.  Then, show us both the current and expected output from the query you are running.

Comment: I believe Date is a reserved keyword in MySQL. So when I name a column date I always use backtics (`) around the column name like this `Date` to make sure MySQL knows I mean a column name. I hope that's the problem.

Comment: @Rolfie `date` is not reserved. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html (Note `(R)` denotes reserved).

Comment: I changed the column name 'date' to 'Mdate' and the query respectively. The problem still exists.

Comment: This would give you invalid HTML. It would give you `<td>`'s in `<td>`'s.

Comment: @user3783243 Still not a bad practise to use backtics. I didn't know they were filtered out here when you make a comment.

Comment: @Rolfie Yea, just not the issue here. The backticks aren't filtered out, they are used for code blocks. They need to be escaped to be literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `fetch` call advances the row count 1 position. Only have the `while` fetch call. Remove the preceding one (or comment it out, as I have to show).

```
//$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$Pr1 = '';
$Pr2 = '';
$Pr3 = '';
$Pr4 = '';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

Answer (score 1):

You discard the first line...

```
$sql="SELECT Pr1, Pr2, Pr3, Pr4 FROM Tbdata ORDER BY Date DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);   // Reads row, comment this out
```

Comment out that last line.

Also as you wrap each item in `<td>` tags, you don't need them in...

```
<td>'.$Pr4.'</td>
```

So remove the `<td>` and `</td>` tags in these.